# How to get market cap of a coin using the CoinGecko C# API?

Tags: c#, .net, documentation, bitcoin, coingecko

I narrowed it down to:

```
ICoinGeckoClient CGClient = CoinGeckoClient.Instance;
var result2 = CGClient.CoinsClient.GetAllCoinsData ();
```

but I have to provide some arguments to GetAllCoinsData, but they don't make a lot of sense to me and I couldn't find any mention of this function or the original CoinGecko function seems to be a web based API. So not sure how I can pass a symbol, etc and get the coin data back to get the market cap data.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: https://www.coingecko.com/en/api is their documentation. It looks like they have an API call to get all coin symbols. Then with the symbols you can use the get coin by symbol call which has market cap.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should use

```
        Task<CoinFullDataById> GetAllCoinDataWithId(string id);
```

Using the propper id.

There is a id/symbol list at: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wTTuxXt8n9q7C4NDXqQpI3wpKu1_5bGVmP9Xz0XGSyU/edit#gid=0

You can also download the code and check the comments/tests at: https://github.com/tosunthex/CoinGecko

```
        /// <summary>
    /// List all coins with data (name, price, market, developer, community, etc) - paginated by 50
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Task<IReadOnlyList<CoinFullData>> GetAllCoinsData();

    /// <summary>
    /// List all coins with data (name, price, market, developer, community, etc) - paginated by 50
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="order">order by</param>
    /// <param name="perPage">Total results per page</param>
    /// <param name="page">Page through results</param>
    /// <param name="localization">Set to false to exclude localized languages in response</param>
    /// <param name="sparkline">Include sparkline 7 days data (true/false) [default: false]</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Task<IReadOnlyList<CoinFullData>> GetAllCoinsData(string order, int? perPage, int? page, string localization,
        bool? sparkline);
```